# Unserialize data of database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, serialization

How can unserialize, data stored in database with serialize?
Please give me example.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($upload_data as $file) {
  $result[] = $file['file'];
}
$insert_to_database = serialize($result);
//This inserted in database, I want unserialize this output
output: a:2:{i:0;s:55:"Chrysanthemum18.jpg";i:1;s:48:"Desert18.jpg";}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php ?

Comment: please give me example. i see it but not Understand

Comment: Example are here: http://php.net/unserialize Scroll down for examples and also have a look at the comments.

Comment: @Mehd S: Any of the answers or comments worked for you? Or do you still have a problem to understand the meaning of the `serialize` / `unserialize` functions?

Answer (score 3):

Use [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

```
$var = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$var = serialize($var);
var_dump($var); // string(42) "a:3:{i:0;s:1:"a";i:1;s:1:"b";i:2;s:1:"c";}"
$var = unserialize($var);
echo $var[0]; // 'a'
```

Comment: [PHP Serialize() & Unserialize() Issues](http://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues)

Comment: @W.Kristianto: couldn't reproduce his issue, `<?php var_dump(unserialize(serialize(array('"', "'", ':', ';'))));` produces the expected result. I'm pretty sure his issue is that his serialized string is truncated at some point, or he stores it as a c string without knowing that it can contains special characters including NULL ( \0 ) in the middle of it (eg it won't work properly in some cases if stored in a postgresql "text" field, you need bytea instead). Not sure if mysql varchar/text allows for \0, if not binary field should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you use CI AR to retrieve the serialized data...

```
$qry = $this->db->select('your_serialized_field')
                 ->from('some_table')
                 ->get();
$serialized_data = $qry->result_array();
$unserialized_data = array();
// Then for every record...
foreach($serialized_data as $single_record)
{
   $unserialized_data[] = unserialize($single_record);
}
// You now can see your array
var_dump($unserialized_data);
```